# Getting $Ros_distro in c++ code

Tags: ros, linux, ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to ask like is there a way to get the ROS_DISTRO in c++, cz I want to run specific C++ code when ros_distro is melodic, and else if noetic then this code.
Ubuntu: 20.04
Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391289/getting-$ros_distro-in-c++-code./) by [AB4147](https://answers.ros.org/users/57972/ab4147/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sure there is a simpler way, but this is how I will do if I am in a pinch.
Since `echo $ROS_DISTRO` will give me the information, then I will use a program to read the output of this command:

From this [example](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/c-programming/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-linux-command-in-c/) I will make a slight modification accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

string GetStdoutFromCommand(string cmd) {

  string data;
  FILE * stream;
  const int max_buffer = 256;
  char buffer[max_buffer];
  cmd.append(" 2>&1");

  stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
  if (stream) {
    while (!feof(stream))
      if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) != NULL) data.append(buffer);
    pclose(stream);
  }
  return data;
}

int main() {

  string ros_version = GetStdoutFromCommand("echo $ROS_DISTRO");
  cout << "ROS version: " << ros_version << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-19**:
`ROS_DISTRO` is an environment variable.

Why not just read the environment variable with the appropriate functions? See [std::getenv(..)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

And actually, using conditional compilation might even be better.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-19**:
@gvdhoorn that's way better than what I propose!